# WPF/XAML: How to get multiple controls/elements to use the same handler for a non-routed event

Tags: wpf, xaml, events

I would like to use the same handler for standard non-routed .NET events for several controls. I have the following xaml. Later in the xaml code I declare another ModelVisual3D with a newton:ConvexBody3D and I want that ConvexBody3D to use the same handler (BodyApplyForce) for the ApplyForce event which is a non-routed event.
When running the application, the ApplyForce event is only raised for the ConvexBody3D that is declared first and never for consecutive ConvexBody3Ds. How can I use the same event handler for all my ConvexBody3Ds?

```
<ModelVisual3D x:Name="Box1" >
    <newton:World.Body>
        <newton:ConvexBody3D x:Name="blueCube" Mass="0.1" ApplyForce="BodyApplyForce"/>
    </newton:World.Body>
```

Comment: I don't know the classes, but if it is a normal c# event, i think thats a limitation of the XAML parser. But what about using a "proxy" routed event, that just calls the senders "normal" event?